# Common practice for creating software switchable power rails

Tags: power-supply, power, switch-mode-power-supply, design

I have created a circuit which has a HackHD camera attached to it. To turn on and off the video, you drive a pin to ground for a fraction of a section. The GPIO pin fluctuates on boot, which triggers the camera into an unknown state. I'd like to prevent the camera from coming on till the system is ready (which could be many hours later).

My solution so far has been to create a power rail I can turn on and off to control if power is reaching my attached sensors (such as the camera). Is there a common way to create this, or should I just use some Half-H Bridge drivers to turn on and off the power when I want? I was considering using the SN754410 HBridge chip. https://www.sparkfun.com/datasheets/IC/SN754410.pdf

All thoughts are welcome.

Cheers,

Gregg

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need a bridge circuit, just a single pass element between the power supply and the device.  This is usually a P channel FET if the supply voltage is 12 V or more.  That allows turning on the device by driving the FET gate 12 V below the power rail.  If the power voltage is enough for the full gate voltage to turn on the FET well, but less than the maximum allowed gate voltage, then this is as easy as a low side NPN pulling the gate low to turn the device on, and a resistor pulling the gate high to turn the device off.  Turning off doesn't need to be fast, so the resistor can be fairly high, like 10 kΩ, to avoid taking significant current when on.

If the power to the device is coming from a buck supply, then you only need to shut down the buck converter.  Some buck converter chips have a shutdown input that you could use directly.

### Added

You now say that the power you want to switch is 5 V and that the control signal is 3.3 V.  This can be done with a "logic level" P channel FET.  Those turn on fully with 5 V or so gate drive.  Have the 3.3 V signal turn on a low side NPN.  That pulls the gate down, with a resistor pulling it up otherwise.

You also mention that this 5 V is regulated down from a 7 V or so battery.  This is exactly the case I was talking about where you get a buck converter that includes a shutdown input.  Many do.  At these low voltages, check out the offerings from Microchip.  Of course the usual suspects like TI and ST will have parts too.  Surely something suitable comes with a shutdown input.

Comment: The Camera Voltage is 5v, while the logic voltage is 3.3v. My understanding of FET circuits is still growing. Is this idea still viable with only 5v/3.3v?

Comment: Also, the power is coming from a power regulator, being stepped down from ~7.4 (lipo batteries).

Comment: Could you give more details about the power regulator? As Olin said, it might have a shutdown input, which would do exactly what you want.

Comment: I think I will be checking out one of the dedicated chips as you suggested. I will be ordering the chip soon and work that out. Thanks for your help. Accepting the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Both the Beaglebone Black and Parallax Propeller use 3.3v logic and can not tolerate 5v on their GPIO pins.  So you need to use both a an N-channel and P-channel MOSFET:

[image]

R1 is there to insure the MOSFET is on when the N-channel MOSFET is off. Because of the inverting nature of the N-channel MOSFET, a 0 on the output of the microcontroller turns on the load, and 1 turns it off. Adding a pull-up (R2) to 3.3v on the output of the microcontroller keeps the load off when the circuit first comes up. You will want to configure the microcontroller's output pin as open-drain.

Note there are no resistors in the gate circuits of the FETs, this is because they are voltage-driven devices unlike BJT's whose bases are current-driven.

The DMP2035U has a typical Rds(on) of 23 mΩ and can handle 2.9A continuous, and dissipate 0.8W.

Comment: Thank you @tcrosley, your diagram was very very helpful in understanding how this works. I have decided to go with a dedicated powerchip, with a shut-down pin. Your answer is great though. Thanks for teaching me something!

Answer (score 1):

Adding a power switch has lots of benefits, especially when you consider that you only need to power the camera when you need to and so save power. If that is not important then the simplest solution is to try to stop the GPIO pin from fluctuating during boot. This is quite a common thing, and we would usually call it a "floating" input. The best solution is to pull the pin to a known state on power up using a high value resistor. From what you have said you should pull the pin to a positive supply rail with a 100k Ohm resistor. It is important that you use the correct positive rail. You didn't say what processor or module you are using so it is difficult to give a definite recommendation, but you probably need to use the same supply that powers the GPIO pin of the processor. If you post details of the processor we can give further advice.

Comment: Thanks for the though. The MCU is a BeagleBone Black (but might also be a Parallax Propeller). I originally tried your pull-up idea, but I think the GPIO pin isn't floating, but rather, MUX'ed into another function during startup. The power switch idea won't work for my application, as the timing of the power on needs to be computer driven.

Comment: To complete my thought more from above, I believe the GPIO pin is actually pulled low during this startup phase.

Comment: This is a good point here, I have upvote, because it might be an issue with someone else that is having this same problem.

Answer (score 0):

A P-Channel FET is a simpler solution than an H bridge, depending on your power requirements. A supply voltage supervisor (MAX809 and similar) is a better solution to your problem.

Comment: Thanks, I ended up accepting the other answer that is the same, but appreciate your thoughts.